# Could not find function "OlsonNames" when using read_csv with readr package

Tags: r, csv, readr

I am trying to read a csv file using read_csv() of R.

```
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("data/tmp.csv")
```

tmp.csv is given below.

```
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"
1,5,2015-07-31,5263,555,1,1,"0","1"
2,5,2015-07-31,6064,625,1,1,"0","1"
3,5,2015-07-31,8314,821,1,1,"0","1"
4,5,2015-07-31,13995,1498,1,1,"0","1"
5,5,2015-07-31,4822,559,1,1,"0","1"
6,5,2015-07-31,5651,589,1,1,"0","1"
7,5,2015-07-31,15344,1414,1,1,"0","1"
8,5,2015-07-31,8492,833,1,1,"0","1"
9,5,2015-07-31,8565,687,1,1,"0","1"
```

But it produces the following error.

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  could not find function "OlsonNames"
```

How can I solve this error? I have googled using the error, but haven't found any relevant solution.

---

After some digging, the same error occurs with:

```
> locale()
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  could not find function "OlsonNames"
```

It seems like an error relating to https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/timezones.html

Restarting the R session doesn't work.

**How should I resolve the error? Do I need to install some packages? If so, which?**

Comment: Have you tried it with `read.csv`.  I tried with `read_csv` and couldn't get any error.  I used  readr_0.2.2

Comment: I’m assuming you’re referring to `readr::read_csv`? **Say so**.

Comment: I think your session is messed up. `OlsonNames` doesn't seem related, and even if it is, you should have this function. Try restarting your R session.

Comment: what is the result of `find("read_csv")` ?

Comment: Thanks. read.csv() has solved the error.
@BenBolker
> find("read_csv")
[1] "package:readr".

But why negative vote?

Comment: @DavidArenburg No, it’s related: `readr::read_csv` calls `locale` which in turn calls `check_tz`, which uses `OlsonNames`. And yes, the R session seems to be messed up.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I think it's a version error. Instead of asking another question and get closed, might as well just add to the question and wait for the OP to confirm it =) @qmaruf, please confirm this.

Comment: @alvas imho, your session info under OP's question doesn't really aid in answering their question.

Comment: @heroka, no problem, I have added the info into my answer instead

Answer (score 3):

Updating R seems to resolve the problem.

To update to *R 3.2.2 for Ubuntu 14.04* (**ONLY WORKS for Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty**, update the deb packages properly if you're not using 14.04):

```
sudo echo 'deb http://cran.es.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

(Update instructions from: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264580)
Then in the latest version of R:

```
> install.packages('readr')
> library(readr)
> locale()
<locale>
Numbers:  123,456.78
Formats:  %Y%.%m%.%d / %H:%M
Timezone: UTC
Encoding: UTF-8
<date_names>
Days:   Sunday (Sun), Monday (Mon), Tuesday (Tue), Wednesday (Wed), Thursday
        (Thu), Friday (Fri), Saturday (Sat)
Months: January (Jan), February (Feb), March (Mar), April (Apr), May (May),
        June (Jun), July (Jul), August (Aug), September (Sep), October
        (Oct), November (Nov), December (Dec)
AM/PM:  AM/PM
```

Now loading the `read_csv` works without the `OlsonNames` error.

---

Before updating my R, this is my R version:

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu         
arch           x86_64                      
os             linux-gnu                   
system         x86_64, linux-gnu           
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          0.2                         
year           2013                        
month          09                          
day            25                          
svn rev        63987                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
nickname       Frisbee Sailing
```

Comment: Although this answer works, it would be nice if someone gives an authoritative answer as to why the error occurs and why updating R works.

Comment: Using read.csv() has solved the issue. As I am beginner, I don't know the exact reason.

Comment: I'm not sure too, I think it's an old version of `readr.read.csv()` vs the newer version of `readr.read_csv()`. I'm not very sure how R's `readr` package works. Someone more experienced should answer that =(

Answer (score 3):

Let's say a package `Pkg` has a function `Foo`.

When you see a message like:

`Could not find function Foo`

this means `Pkg` has not been loaded successfully (i.e. by `library/require` command).Or if `Pkg` is required indrectly by your package (i.e. `readr` in this case) it may be that `Pkg` is not installed, or your R installation is somehow broken. That's why an update/upgrade or even restart the computer may help.

In this case the function `OlsonNames` (try typing this in R console: `??OlsonNames`) is an alias to `base::Sys.timezone` function. Because it belongs to the base package, which is certainly has been installed, it is likely that something odd happened with your R installation. Then again, a fresh R session by restarting or update/upgrade of R may help.

**Bonus:**
This is often overlooked by many, an easy method given by R developers themselves to **get the latest version of R on Linux**:

Select a mirror near you from here:
https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html
For example, I select a mirror in Denmark, then read the README.
http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/cran/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html

I also had great comfort to maintain R installation on Windows with `installr` package. Github: https://github.com/talgalili/installr/

Comment: I agree that updating R often solves the problem on linux but there's nothing wrong with my session when that `OlsonNames` error occurs because that's the first R session created since I did `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev` and then in R `install.package('readr')`on that particular machine. So it couldn't have been an error of the session.